# Asp.Net Role Based Authentication?

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, forms-authentication, role-base-authorization

I want to redirect user based upon role.I can do it without using Forms Authentication but I want to do it with forms authentication. Following is my code:

**Web.Config**

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="Forms/Login.aspx" defaultUrl="Member/Home.aspx">
  </forms>
</authentication>

<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

**Login.aspx.cs**

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        members.memberEmail = txtEmail.Text;
        members.memberPassword = operation.EncodePasswordToBase64(txtPassword.Text);
        DataSet ds = operation.GetUsers(members);
        if (ds != null)
        {
            int role = int.Parse(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["memberType"].ToString());
            if (role == 2)
            {
                Response.Redirect("../Member/Home.aspx");
            }
            else if(role == 1)
            {
                Response.Redirect("../Admin/Home.aspx");
            }
        }
    }
```

Here GetUsers function giving back the Dataset of members and I am checking role from DataSet and redirecting the user to respective home page. I am trying to accomplish same thing using forms authentication:

I have enabled the role manager in web config:

```
<roleManager enabled="true">
</roleManager>
```

I know, I am doing wrong. Can anyone guide me?

Comment: You're missing a lot!!!! Maybe follow this [guide](https://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/roles/role-based-authorization-cs).